# My bixolon srp-350ii printer print every thing twice?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I have a bixolon srp-350ii printer, any time I try to print or test print it printed the recipient twice, since number of copy=1.When I put number of copy to 2 it print 4 times, if 3 print 6 times and so on. What's the way to fix this problem, I tried to reinstall the driver but the problem stills. Or any way to reset this type of printer

Answer (score 0):

The driver itself may have a setting for copies. If that is set to 2, it will multiply the application's copy count by 2.

Go to Devices and Printers, click on Printer Properties > Advanced tab > Printing Defaults button, and have a look under all the tabs and buttons. Many printers have it under an Advanced button.

Answer (score 0):

I know It is an old question, but as I've spent 2 hours trying to fix this I thought I should post the answer. In my case It was a switch located in the bottom of the printer, under a metal lid. If the switch 7 of the first block is on the printer always prints a duplicate.